# Datepicker do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Desenvolvi uma aplicação usando o bootstrap (getbootstrap.com).
Crei um campo data  e vinculei o datepicker do próprio bootstrap.
Como fazer para alterar o tamanho do calendário? Preciso exibi-lo menor.

[image: Modo como está sendo exibido.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use no seu CSS o seguinte:

```
.datepicker table tr td{
   width:auto !important;
   height: auto !important;
   font-size: 11px !important;
}
```

Para alterar o tamanho do [datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) basta alterar o tamanho da font.

Answer (score 1):

Abre o Console do Navegador, inspeciona o elemento, pegue as classe e as utilize em um CSS separado editando-as diretivas e inserindo a flag !important.